# Entity Framework And MSBI Application

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am in the process of Designing BI Solution. I am going to use MSBI and ADO.net Entity Framework (Latest version).

Questions:

1. Which way to go `Code 1st` or `Model/Data Base 1st`?
2. How Can Entity Framework additionally help me to build BI application with the Standard MSBI Tools?

this help will really help me to go ahead !

Regards!

Vineet

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is basic ORM for mapping OLTP database to .NET objects with ability to query that mapped database with linq-to-entities / ESQL converted to common SQL. If you need anything like that it will help you.

If you need SSAS, MDX queries, SSIS, SSRS it will not help you. It will only reduce performance of everything.

Comment: Reason To take on MSBI here the Key factor is size of the database that will definatly stands out 15+ GB. And i have to query such a huge DB for analysis.

Comment: In such case you don't need EF.

Answer (score 0):

To query cube in your .Net code, you would need to go for ADOMD.Net which requires `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Adomdclient.dll` reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, you certainly need a data model for your Reporting/Data warehouse database. Only then you should design and develop your ETL.

In this case you won't be needing any Entity Framework.